# Emulate bible verse layout in HTML

Tags: html, mediawiki

I'm trying to emulate the layout of the versing for a wiki where the first verse to come up in each line is displayed before each line. Is this even possible with basic HTML?

http://jsfiddle.net/ukfpj2o8/It

```
<div style="margin-left:2em"><span style="color:#2E8B57; float:left; text-align:right; margin-left:-3em; width:2.5em;" id="I.">I.</span> IN the beginning God made the heaven and the earth. <span style="color:#2E8B57; float:left; text-align:right; margin-left:-3em; width:2.5em;" id="I.">2</span> And the earth was invisible and unfurnished and there was darkness over this abyss; and a breath of God was brought on above the water. <span style="color:#2E8B57; float:left; text-align:right; margin-left:-3em; width:2.5em;" id="I.">3</span> And God said, "Let there be Light;" and there was light. And God saw the light that it was good. <span style="color:#2E8B57; float:left; text-align:right; margin-left:-3em; width:2.5em;" id="I.">4</span>And God made a separation between the light and the darkness. <span style="color:#2E8B57; float:left; text-align:right; margin-left:-3em; width:2.5em;" id="I.">5</span>And God called the light day; and the darkness he called night. And there was an evening and there was a morning. The first day.</div>
```

I hope someone can help
Thanks

Comment: This is not possible with basic HTML, but could be achieved with CSS/JavaScript. Please provide a starting point (CodePen or JSFiddle), see also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Well, how does that page do it?  You can see their HTML.

Comment: Here's what I have come up with. https://jsfiddle.net/jpez/ukfpj2o8/It works fine except when the verse numbers are on the same line the floated spans overlap.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something which works fine for the purpose I need it for. By adding a white background I get rid of the overlapping of the floated verse numbers and by using z-index I can make the first verse in the line display instead of the last which would have been displayed by default. Here is the span used before each verse, verse 1 for example

```
<span style="color:#2E8B57; background-color:#FFFFFF; position:relative; z-index:99; font-size:small; float:left; text-align:right; margin-left:-3em; width:2.5em;">1</span>
```

verse 2 would have a z-index value of 98, verse 3, 97 etc